# WPF MenuItem Click when ItemsSource bound to objects

Tags: c#, wpf, object, menuitem

I have a collection of Item-Objects bound to a WPF MenuItem ItemsSource

```
public class Item
{
public string Name
public ?? MethodToCall
}
```

Now i want to use my click event (I will probably use a RelayCommand) to call the `MethodToCall`, which is `void`. So what is the type `??` in my `Item` object, which i should use? And what should be in the RelayCommand? Just simply `Item.MethodToCall()`? I dont want to use any `case` or something, as i want to be able to dynamically add items to the `MenuItem` and define in the corresponding object my Method. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your relay command calling a method would look like :

```
private bool _canExecuteMyCommand = true;
public RelayCommand YourCommand 
{ 
  get; 
  private set; 
} 

public MainViewModel() 
{ 
  MyCommand = new RelayCommand( MethodToCall, () => _canExecuteMyCommand); 
} 

private void MethodToCall() 
{ 
  // Do something 
}
```

`_canExecuteMyCommand` decides when the command shall be executed. ie when the `MethodToCall` function is called. If it is false, then the function is not called.

**EDIT :**

You can have multiple relay commands within the class ie within the `Item` class as follows :

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name
    public RelayCommand YourCommand1 
    { 
      get; 
      private set; 
    } 

    public RelayCommand YourCommand2 
    { 
      get; 
      private set; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's assume I have two objects (new and print for example) in the collection bound to the MenuItem. The relay command would get the object as parameter. Now I want to execute new() or print() depending which one was clicked. This should be rather easy I guess, but I don't know what my ?? Is in the original question and how to execute the method in the relay command without calling an explicit method (it should be the method from the Item object and no matter how many of these objects are in the collection for MenuItem.

Comment: I think you need to add multiple relay commands to the Item class as mentioned above. Please recheck the answer  I have posted.